# A WebException with status SecureChannelFailure was thrown on Windows 2008

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

I have written a POC that sends SNS messages from a .nety application to the AWS SNS.
It works fine when installed on my Win 7 laptop. But when i install it on a Windows Server 2008 it gives me this error message.

I am pretty sure the code is fine since it works on the laptop install.
This is the error ,

```
11/28/2017 8:20:34 PM:
A WebException with status SecureChannelFailure was thrown.
11/28/2017 8:20:34 PM:
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.WebExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, WebException exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller)
   at Amazon.SecurityToken.AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient.AssumeRole(AssumeRoleRequest request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out this one myself.
So my .NET application was using framework 3.5 which does not support TLS 1.2 .
I migrated my project to .NET 4.5 and added a line to make sure we always use TLS 1.2 as that is the de facto standard now after the poodle attack thing.

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

This fixed my issue.
Mostly this error has to be related to your security configuration be it your runtime or the system in general.